How to configure AmnesiaWG VPN for browser-only use (like VPN extensions)
I'm using Amnesia WG VPN on a VDS server and want to configure my VPN to work only through my browser, similar to how VPN extensions operate (e.g., for Chrome or Firefox). The idea is that the rest of my system traffic doesn't go through the VPN—only the browser does. I want to use my own Amnesia WG configuration, not a third-party VPN provider.
I've considered the following options but haven't found a complete solution yet:

Brave Browser VPN: Brave has built-in VPN functionality but uses its own infrastructure rather than custom configs​

Outline VPN: Outline can run VPN via the browser, but also requires managing separate servers

OpenConnect: This is configurable for HTTPS-based VPNs, but doesn’t seem to easily adapt for Amnesia WG or browser-only routing


Does anyone have experience or insight on setting up WireGuard/Amnesia WG for browser-only traffic? Ideally, I'd like to keep my config but emulate the functionality of a VPN browser extension. Any suggestions on specific software, browser settings, or scripts that could help would be appreciated!
